# PHP version for ORACLE12C

Tags: php, oracle12c

In my project I am using **oracle12c**.
We are planning to use **Drupal** for content management system. 
Now which version of **php** and **drupal** i have to use for compatability with oracle12c

Comment: The latest version of php manual tell this -> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.oci8.php so you can use the latest php stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is not a good database choice for Drupal.  There is no native support in Drupal for it and although there is a module that provides Oracle support there is no active development (other then bug fixes) and that module does not yet support Drupal 8.

Your best choice (other than not using Oracle) would be the latest stable version of php 5.5 (5.5.26) with PDO (OCI is not supported in the Oracle module) and the latest version of Drupal 7 (7.38) with the Oracle module installed.